# Failed to upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: 16.04, upgrade

I was working in my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS when the upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10  pop-up.

I just click install and after a lot of hours a error message pop-up:

```
Failed to upgrade to ubuntu 17.10. Your system ay have been trash.
```

Any idea why this happened?

Comment: 17.10 goes out of support soon and will not receive security updates. You should install 18.04 instead.

Comment: Since your error message seems suspicious on several levels (perhaps you miscopied it?), we gently suggest that you clean-install a fresh copy of 18.04.

Comment: fyi:  16.04 LTS won't have offered any upgrades yet, it's next upgrade is to 18.04 and this is only offered after the 18.04.1 release which isn't till late July.  Even if you'd attempted to `do-release-upgrade` from 16.04, you'd get a no new release message (as the upgrade path opens at 18.04.1).  LTS upgrades only to LTS with pop-ups.